# Django failing to load 400.html

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, apache

I've defined custom templates for errors 400, and 404 for my Django project. When I try to access the production version of my site, the error 404 template is correctly loaded for missing pages. However, if I send a bad request to my Apache/Django server (e.g. `http://mysite.example.com/%`), the template for the error 400 is not loaded, instead, the regular Apache error page is rendered:

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at mysite.example.com Port 80
```

Is apache relaying this request to Django at all, or do I need to define `handler400` in my Django project in order for this to work (though I didn't have to do that for the `404.html`)?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/759959/why-does-the-percent-sign-in-a-url-cause-an-http-400-bad-request-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crucial point here is that your apache is acting as a proxy for your usgi server. It's forwarding all valid requests to usgi, a request for a non existent request is a valid request as far as apache is concerned and needs the forwarded to the django router - which will find that the url mapping does not exist and raise a 404 error. This error is done internally by django and results in the django 404 page being shown.

Some requests, most notably the django rest framework produce 400 responses internally when the serializers fail to validate the incoming json request. Those will also result in the django 400 page being shown.

However if the request itself is malformed, it will never be forwarded to the usgi server and django will never see it. it will be handled internally by apache hence the reason that the apache 400 html is shown.

The simplest solution would be to replace all the apache error pages with the corresponding django one (if these are templates, render them and save the html)

Comment: I though so... Is there a way to send a bad request (through the browser) that would be passed from Apache to uWSGI and then I could see the properly rendered html?

Comment: I am not that much of an expert on apache, but i think it would be possible. Please search for RewriteRule or RewriteCond based on http status